How to set unique accessibilityidentifier on button label in SwiftUI
I've recently started working with SwiftUI and have been trying to implement Maestro testing into my app. Maestro accesses various things by looking at their accessibilityIdentifier property, this way you can get the relevant button to simulate a button presses on or check a specific text box has the text you want. I have been adding these properties fine so far but I have been unable to add a unique accessibilityIdentifier to a button with a label. Here is my (slightly simplified) button:
            Button {
                //Button implementation
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Text")
                            .accessibilityIdentifier("Textbox")
                        Image(.rightArrow)
                    }
                    .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
                    .accessibilityIdentifier("Container")
                }

            }

All this does is make the Button element have the "Textbox" identifier. I want the Label to have 2 unique labels, one for the container and one for the text and I may add an identifier for the image in future. Would this even be possible?
Button only has one identifier
Textbox identifier is used
I looked at this post as I was initially struggling to even get the inner child elements to have unique identifiers but using .accessibilityElement(children: .contain) before the .accessibilityIdentifier("Container") seemed to do the job. It stopped working correctly as soon as I put it inside a button label though so I hope I can get the same functionality just inside a button

It's better not to assign any accessibility stuff to button's label components. Button as a whole is a single accessibility component, that shouldn't have children as it receives the touch as a whole. Just assign the accessibility id to the button.

Something like:
Button { // Action } label: { 
  //label
}
.acceciblityIdentifier("Example")

You could also try to have the inner child elements inherit the same identifier and use them in different contexts since I don't think any one of them are of the same View Type

This doesn't solve the issue of using two identifiers, how would I have a test that is able to both do a button press (button identifier) and check the button's text is correct (inner text identifier)
